# How to edit last delimiter of biblatex APA in \texcite?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am using the biblatex APA style and I try to change the delimiter between the second-last and last references in textcite.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=spanish]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sortcites]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Book{Atkinson1999,
author    = {Atkinson, Anthony Barnes},
title     = {The economic consequences of rolling back the {W}elfare {S}tate},
year      = {1999},
publisher = {MIT press},
location  = {Londres},
}
@Article{Atkinson1995,
author    = {Atkinson, Anthony Barnes},
title     = {The {W}elfare {S}tate and economic performance},
journal   = {National Tax Journal},
year      = {1995},
volume    = {48},
number    = {2},
pages     = {171--198},
}
@Book{Tuning2003,
author    = {Gonz{\'a}lez, Julia and Wagenaar, Robert},
title     = {\emph{{T}uning {E}ducational {S}tructures in {E}urope}. Informe final. Fase 1},
year      = {2003},
publisher = {Universidad de Deusto},
location  = {Bilbao},
}
@Book{Tuning2006,
author    = {Gonz{\'a}lez, Julia and Wagenaar, Robert},
title     = {\emph{{T}uning {E}ducational {S}tructures in {E}urope}. Informe final. Fase 2},
year      = {2006},
publisher = {Universidad de Deusto},
location  = {Bilbao},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\textcite{Atkinson1995, Atkinson1999, Tuning2003, Tuning2006}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Basically, I would like to obtain

Atkinson (1995, 1999) and González and Wagenaar (2003, 2006).

However, I am only able to get

Atkinson (1995, 1999), González and Wagenaar (2003, 2006).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` does not use `\textcitedelim`, instead it has `\compcitedelim` everywhere. In order to enable `\textcitedelim` we need to implement a two-pass structure of `\textcite` as in `authoryear-icomp.cbx`. The code therefore is quite something.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=spanish]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sortcites]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Book{Atkinson1999,
author    = {Atkinson, Anthony Barnes},
title     = {The economic consequences of rolling back the {W}elfare {S}tate},
year      = {1999},
publisher = {MIT press},
location  = {Londres},
}
@Article{Atkinson1995,
author    = {Atkinson, Anthony Barnes},
title     = {The {W}elfare {S}tate and economic performance},
journal   = {National Tax Journal},
year      = {1995},
volume    = {48},
number    = {2},
pages     = {171--198},
}
@Book{Tuning2003,
author    = {Gonz{\'a}lez, Julia and Wagenaar, Robert},
title     = {\emph{{T}uning {E}ducational {S}tructures in {E}urope}. Informe final. Fase 1},
year      = {2003},
publisher = {Universidad de Deusto},
location  = {Bilbao},
}
@Book{Tuning2006,
author    = {Gonz{\'a}lez, Julia and Wagenaar, Robert},
title     = {\emph{{T}uning {E}ducational {S}tructures in {E}urope}. Informe final. Fase 2},
year      = {2006},
publisher = {Universidad de Deusto},
location  = {Bilbao},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
% from authoryear-icomp.cbx
\renewcommand*{\iffinalcitedelim}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{textcitecount}}{\value{textcitetotal}-1}}

% from apa.cbx with only \stepcounter{textcitecount} added in the second-to-last line
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}
% Compact cite - more than one thing for same author
    {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}}
% New cite
    {%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
      \setunit{\textcitedelim}%
      \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{patent}}
  % No author/editor or patent
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    % Cite using title
         {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
          \setunit{\ifbool{cbx:np}%
                   {\nameyeardelim}%
                   {\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}}
    % Cite using shorthand
         {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
  % Normal cite with author/editor
  % Normal full cite
       {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}%
    % Normal full cite
         {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{labelname}}
    % Cite using short author
         {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
           {\printnames{shortauthor}}
           {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{author}}}%
  % Year
        \setunit{\ifbool{cbx:np}
                  {\nameyeardelim}
                  {\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
  % Put the shortauthor inside the year brackets if necessary
        \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
         {}
         {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
           {}
           {\printnames{shortauthor}\setunit{\nameyeardelim}}}%
  % Actual year printing
        \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}%
  % Save name hash for checks later
        \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
        \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}

% this is \textcite from apa.cbx renamed
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}

% this is cite:init from authoryear-icomp.cbx renamed to avoid name clashes
\newbibmacro*{textcite:init}{%
  \ifnumless{\value{multicitecount}}{2}
    {\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
     \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
     \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}
    {\iffieldundef{prenote}
       {}
       {\global\undef\cbx@lasthash
        \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}}

% from authoryear-icomp.cbx with cite:init -> textcite:init
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

% textcite has nested \DeclareCiteCommand definitions for textcite and we want to use
% the normal textcite context
\DeclareDelimcontextAlias{cbx@textcite}{textcite}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@textcite@init}[2]{%
  \setcounter{textcitetotal}{0}%
  \setcounter{textcitecount}{0}%
  \def\cbx@savedcites{#1}#2\cbx@savedcites\empty}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\textcite{Atkinson1995, Atkinson1999, Tuning2003, Tuning2006}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example citation]

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to modify the code to get the "y" between both references Atkinson and González y Wagenaar as smartand, that is, "y" or "e" if the word starts by "e"?

I am trying to do that even modifying spanish-apa but I am not able to find where I should make the change.

Comment: @NachoAntón Mhhh, `spanish-apa.lbx` turns the smartand off explicitly: `\setcounter{smartand}{0} % Turn off "smart and" or ampersands will all be replaced`